# Problem in Opening Console of Db2 Warehouse

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to open Db2 of IBM, but there comes a 502 Gateway problem. It continues for 2 hours already. What can be the reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor. Have you tried opening a support case?

Comment: This likely should be addressed with vendor. One quick thing to test is to restart the console with:
```
/opt/ibm/dsserver/bin/stop.sh
/opt/ibm/dsserver/bin/start.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart the web console server as given steps above.